# Yii2 Yii::$app->user->identity->id returns an error instead of redirecting to login page

Tags: yii2

in my behaviours I have specified that `actionList` can only be viewed by authenticated users.

```
$behaviors [ 'access' ] = [
    'class' => AccessControl::className(),
    'rules' => [
        [
            'actions' => [ 'list' ],
            'allow'   => ['@'],
        ]
    ],
];
```

In `actionList` I'm getting the `user_id`:

```
public function actionList() {
    $user_id  = \Yii::$app->user->identity->id;
    return $this->render( 'list' );
}
```

All good, but if you go to this action when not logged in, you get an error:

> PHP Notice – yii\base\ErrorException
>
> Trying to get property of non-object

Makes sense, I'm not logged in so I don't have a user id, but why does the code go that far? If I comment the `$user_id  = \Yii::$app->user->identity->id;` out, I get redirected to the login page, which is the expected behaviour. I don't think I should have to do yet another check to see if someone is logged in in the action itself, shouldn't that be handled by the `behaviours['access']` beforehand?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this changing the `allow` and `roles` attributes:

```
public function behaviors()
{
    return [
        'access' => [
            'class' => AccessControl::className(),
            'rules' => [
                [
                    'actions' => ['list'],
                    'allow' => true,
                    'roles' => ['@'],
                ],
            ], // rules
        ], // access
    ];
}
```

More info [here](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-security-authorization.html).

Answer (score 0):

Here is my cent to the already good answers above

Add following code to the main controller file in your project (not the base controller) but some controller above this which is base for every other controller

```
/**
 * Check if user is logged in and not logged out
 * 
 * @param type $action
 * @return type
 */
public function beforeAction($action) {
    $this->enableCsrfValidation = false;
    if(!empty($action) && $action->actionMethod == 'actionLogin') {
        return true;
    }

    /* Check User's Login Status */
    if (is_null(Yii::$app->user->identity)) {
        $this->redirect(Url::to(['../site/login']));
        Yii::$app->end();
    }

    return true;
}
```